# Did package.xml format change to package.xml-meta.xml?

Tags: salesforcedx, package.xml, manifest

I've been able to retrieve the manifest from my org for quite some time, but today it suddenly stopped working. And is expecting that I change the file path from package.xml --> package.xml-meta.xml.

The error I get with standard package.xml is: 
[image]

Is this a new thing?

Once I changed it over I was getting a different error and can no longer deploy the source manifest or retrieve.

When I attempt to retrieve: It says that there

`Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}members invalid at this location in type Package`

When I attempt to deploy: It says that I am missing a class which is most likely been added by one of our other devs. Which is what I'm tryin got bring in on the retrieve.

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything in the release notes or elsewhere. I think you may have accidentally drag-and-dropped a file or something? Or, it could be a bug in the DX CLI. Couldn't you just right-click on force-app (or whatever you called your folder) and choose "SFDX: Deploy to Org"?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the specific error when using package.xml? I'll send a message out on social media and see if I can get a response.

Comment: That is the error I get when right-clicking for retrieve in the terminal. Are you talking about the error message prior to changing the package.xml --> package.xml-meta.xml? The file hasn't been dragged or dropped into the file tree.

Comment: @sfdcfox just added the screen shot.

Comment: I just got almost the exact same error, and it turns out the error was pointing me right to the problem.  I had an incorrect entry under <types>.  Your error message might be saying that you have an invalid <members> entry under type <name>Package</name>.

Comment: @TalkinData I think it might have been. Would have to go back and check on it. What did you do to correct?

Comment: @thinker - In my case, I had a typo in one of my xml tags in my package.xml file (something like <nMembers>).  I fixed the typo and then metadata retrieve command ran successfully.
    
I would check in the 'Package' section of your package.xml file (types > name : Package) and make sure that all the XML is valid and that it doesn't include a member which either doesn't exist in your org or is spelled incorrectly.  


`<types>
      <members>*</members>
       <name>Package</name>
</types>`

Comment: Thanks @TalkinData. I will investigate that and see if the error occurs again.